# Adding a nested input text

Tags: jquery, input, nested

Still the same problem:

Should add dynamic input text in a question-answers quiz but some problems with answers!
I don't know if I can't get the question's name because it's dynamic, or I write down something wrong to refer to it.
Here it's the code

```
$(function() {

var domande=1;
var indice= new Array();
var contatore=1;
var numero_domanda=1;

$('a.addd').click(function() {

    $('<div class="question">Domanda N:'+domande+'<input type="text" name="'+domande+'" /></br></div><a href="#" name="one" class="addr"><img src="add.png" /></a></br>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('.content');
    domande++;
    indice[domande]=0;
});




$('a.addr').click(function() {

    numero_domanda=$(':input').attr('name');//recupero il nome della domanda
    //numero_domanda=$(.closest('.class').find('input').attr('name'));
    indice[numero_domanda]++;
    $('<div class="answers">risposta N:'+indice[numero_domanda]+'<input type="text" name="r'+numero_domanda+'_'+indice[numero_domanda]+'" /></br></div>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('.question');
    contatore++;

});
```

and the html

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<a href="#" name="one" class="addd"><img src="add.png" /></a></br>
```

With questions it works with answers no....
Wit an only question and multiple answers yes but both no :(

Thanks to every one

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for this to work

```
$('.content').on('click', 'a.addd', function() {

    $('<div class="question">Domanda N:'+domande+'<input type="text" name="'+domande+'" /></br></div><a href="#" name="one" class="addr"><img src="add.png" /></a></br>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('.content');
    domande++;
    indice[domande]=0;
});

$('.content').on('click', 'a.addr', function() {

    numero_domanda=$(':input').attr('name');//recupero il nome della domanda
    //numero_domanda=$(.closest('.class').find('input').attr('name'));
    indice[numero_domanda]++;
    $('<div class="answers">risposta N:'+indice[numero_domanda]+'<input type="text" name="r'+numero_domanda+'_'+indice[numero_domanda]+'" /></br></div>').animate({ opacity: "show" }, "slow").appendTo('.question');
    contatore++;

});
```

Comment: it work ( I had some problems with version of jquery but now it's okay) the problem is that the input text is addes to all the questions but I need to added to a specific one. I think to use css name I'll try at home, would do you think about it? thanks